# How to disable user notifications from my Google Play apk?

Tags: notifications, google-play

I've put an apk in Google Play and made a few changes on the original version, but some users already downloaded it. I'd like to know if it's possible to update de actual version in Google Play, but not notify the users of this update.

Comment: Why exactly do you want your users to be not notified about the update?

Comment: Actually it's not my call, my client asked for that... always make little changes in the code without telling the current users, just tell them about the big or significant updates. Is there any way I can do it?